# MariaDB select where in array of values

Tags: node.js, select, mariadb

I have an array of values `let arr = ['val1', 'val2']`
I want to select rows in which some row equal to one of this value

```
pool.query("select id from sometable where somerow in (" + arr + ")", 
      function (err, rows) {
                if (err) return console.log(err)
                console.log(rows)
            })
```

But i get an error `'Unknown column \'val1\' in \'where clause\'`
I have already tried give `arr.join()` but this doest help.
If i try to find by id and gives array of numbers(ids) everything works great

Answer (score 1):

You could create your query string exactly like this

```js
const inQuery = arr.map('?').join(',');

pool.query(`select id from sometable where somerow in (${inQuery})`, arr, function (err, rows) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(rows);
});
```

`inQuery` will contains exactly `?` times than your array length.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#performing-queries

I think that should work:

```
pool.query("select id from sometable where somerow in (?)", arr, 
    function (err, rows) {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        console.log(rows)
    })
```

Comment: it returns only first value

Comment: You probably need to create the query like `in(?, ?)` (because you have two values).

Comment: Please share your exactly SQL you are using, the database tables (CREATE TABLE) and the result of a SELECT * FROM table;